# Regular expression for validating a username?

Tags: php, regex

I'm still kinda new to using Regular Expressions, so here's my plight. I have some rules for acceptable usernames and I'm trying to make an expression for them.

Here they are:

- 1-15 Characters
- a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and spaces are acceptable
- Must begin with a-z or A-Z
- Cannot end in a space
- Cannot contain two spaces in a row

This is as far as I've gotten with it.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s(?!\s)){0,14}[^\s]$/
```

It works, for the most part, but doesn't match a single character such as "a".

Can anyone help me out here? I'm using PCRE in PHP if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note that `\s` is not just a space but is equal to `[\x09\x0A\x0C\x0D\x20]`.

Comment: Use this(http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp) tool to verify and correct your reg expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?=.{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

The look-ahead assertion `(?=.{1,15}$)` checks the length and the rest checks the structure:

- **`[a-zA-Z]`** ensures that the first character is an alphabetic character;
- **`[a-zA-Z0-9]*`** allows any number of following alphanumeric characters;
- **`(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`** allows any number of sequences of a single space (not `\s` that allows any whitespace character) that must be followed by at least one alphanumeric character (see [*PCRE subpatterns* for the syntax of `(?:…)`](http://php.net/regexp.reference.subpatterns)).

You could also remove the look-ahead assertion and check the length with [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen).

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Could you also explain a little more about how it works? I'm still learning and none of that really make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your regexp is that it needs **at least** two characters two have a match :

- one for the `[a-zA-Z]{1}` part
- one for the `[^\s]` part

Beside this problem, I see some parts of your regexp that could be improved :

- The `[^\s]` class will match **any** character, except spaces : a dot or semi-colon will be accepted, try to use the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` class here to ensure the character is a correct one.
- You can delete the `{1}` part at the beginning, as the regexp will match **exactly** one character by default

Comment: This will match strings with a space at the end

Comment: Now it also matches strings ending with a whitespace character.

Comment: @NUE & Gumbo : Thanks, I didn't realise at first. I removed the incorrect suggestions and focused and the problems of the original regexp.

Answer (score 0):

make everything after your first character optional

```
^[a-zA-Z]?([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s(?!\s)){0,14}[^\s]$
```

Comment: This will also match strings not starting with `[a-zA-Z]` and not ending with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.