# how to validate a text field in jsp using java script for accepting only dot and comma as special characters

Tags: javascript

I need to allow only numerics, dot and comma in a text field. If the user enters other special characters an alert needs to be thrown.

Please find below the conditions:

1. The text field should contain atleast one numeric value.
2. It is not mandatory that the text field should contain dot and comma always.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for validating a username?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821610/regular-expression-for-validating-a-username)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start for you: **http://jsfiddle.net/KLyy8/1/**

Unless you tell us the exact specifics we won't know how to write the regular expression.  Sounds like you want numbers with thousands separator and decimals.  But how many of each?  The fiddle above will work for numbers like this...

123,456.79

12,345.6

1,234.56

etc...

```
validate=function(){
    var str = document.getElementById('test').value;
    var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,2}$");
    var res = patt.test(str);
    alert(res);
}
```

Comment: Good point with the thousand separators. Haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

If the field should contain only numeric values with decimal places (for exmaple `3.14`, `112358` or `9,81`), then you can use only one regex:

```
function validateString(str){
    if(str.match(^[0-9\.,]+$)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

However if you want to be precise you will probably want to limit the dots and commas to one, if I understand your situation correctly.

Regex for that can look like this

```
^[0-9]+(\.|,){0,1}[0-9]+$
```

That means it starts with a number (`^[0-9]+`), then it may contain zero or one times one comma or dot (`(\.|,){0,1}`) and then again ends with a number (`[0-9]+$`).

Comment: The `.*[0-9].*` can be written in a better way, but this works.

Comment: i need not check for alphabets. it is a numeric field. it is not mandatory it should contain '.' and ','. The user may enter only numeric value also.

Comment: So should the field be only numeric+commas+dots?

Comment: yes.but it can also be only numeric. for example the field should accept 11111 and 11..,, also. it should not accept 111@#$%,etc.

Comment: Edited.. This isn't probably the best way around, but I couldn't figure out a regex to check if the string contains only once the decimal point/comma.. :(

Comment: no issues.. if the user enters only . and , without numeric then the system should not accept the value. but when tried ur regex it accepts . and , without a numeric value. Please help me in this.

Comment: Impossible. Use the advanced regex which I posted - `^[0-9]+(\.|,){0,1}[0-9]+$`.. I was testing it out for a while now. Only accepts strings which are in the format described in the regex description.